# Get field API Name of dependent field if picklist has dependency

Tags: apex, dependent-picklist, schema, field-dependencies

Is there a way to retrieve via Schema.DescribeFieldResult field that sets dependency on picklist fields that have isDependentPicklist() true?

For example:

**If my field Field1__c (picklist) has a dependency on Field2__c I want to retrieve Field2__c API Name via Apex and Schema.**

**Is this even possible via Schema or with other kind of functionality?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy:

getController() returns the token of the controlling field.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult result = Lead.Field1__c.getDescribe();

if (result.isDependentPicklist()) {
    system.debug(result.getController()); //Field2__c
}
```

Link on documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find that on first search